# Javascript output with two values returns the word "Object"

Tags: javascript

```
var a = [ 
{"one": "MXLI"},
{"two": "MCCCIIII”"},
{"three": "MCCCXCVIII"},  
{"four": "MCDXLV"},   
{"five": "MDCLXIV"}, 
{"six": "MCMXLIX"},
{"seven": "MMMXICX"}
];

document.write(a + '<br>');
```

I would just like to output both values in my array but i only get:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: `Object.entries(a)`

Comment: and please don't use document.write for anything real

Comment: Try using JSON.stringify(a) instead of just 'a'.

Comment: @Greggz nope, that won't do it - https://jsfiddle.net/mwkj2p4u/ . You'd have to run "entries" on each item within the array, not on the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

you need [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to achieve that:

```
document.write(JSON.stringify(a) + '<br>');
```

working example :

```js
var a = [ 
{"one": "MXLI"},
{"two": "MCCCIIII”"},
{"three": "MCCCXCVIII"},  
{"four": "MCDXLV"},   
{"five": "MDCLXIV"}, 
{"six": "MCMXLIX"},
{"seven": "MMMXICX"}
];


document.write(JSON.stringify(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce function and create a string. In this code `${Object.entries(curr)} \n` `Object.entries` return the key and value of the object where `/n` creates a new line

```js
var a = [{
    "one": "MXLI"
  },
  {
    "two": "MCCCIIII”"
  },
  {
    "three": "MCCCXCVIII"
  },
  {
    "four": "MCDXLV"
  },
  {
    "five": "MDCLXIV"
  },
  {
    "six": "MCMXLIX"
  },
  {
    "seven": "MMMXICX"
  }
];

let str = a.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return acc += `${Object.entries(curr)} \n`;
}, '');

console.log(str)
```